# DAX Measure to calculate aggregate data, but group by Case ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have a variable

```
var varSubItem = CALCULATE (MAX(Outages[SubItem]), Outages[DATE] >= DATE(2019, 07, 14) )
```

to calculate out items that have had an outage within 1 day. See below.

Then I have another variable

```
var data =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
    Outages[SubItem] = devices
)
```

which gives me back the outage count for the devices in the last 2 years. It's only the last two years because my table visual has a filter for that time frame.

I pray that I'm making sense because I have been trying to do this for 2 weeks now.

```
Devices w Outages 2Yr =
VAR devices =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Outages[DEVICE_ID] ), Outages[DATE] >= DATE ( 2019, 07, 14 ) )
VAR data =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DEVICE_ID] = devices
    )
RETURN data
```

I'm getting this,

```
| Area   | Item | SubItem | Case      | Date            | Outage Count |
|--------|------|---------|-----------|-----------------|--------------|
| XXXXX' | ABC1 | 123A    | 123456789 | 7/14/19 1:15 AM | 1            |
|        | ABC2 | 123B    | 132456798 | 7/14/19 3:20 AM | 1            |
|        | ABC3 | 123C    | 984561325 | 7/14/19 6:09 PM | 1            |
|        | ABC4 | 123D    | 789613453 | 7/14/19 3:54 PM | 3            |
|        | ABC5 | 123E    | 335978456 | 7/14/19 2:10 PM | 2            |
| Total  |      |         |           |                 | 8            |
```

When I should be getting this,

```
| Area   | Item | SubItem | Case      | Date            | Outage Count |
|--------|------|---------|-----------|-----------------|--------------|
| XXXXX' | ABC1 | 123A    | 123456789 | 7/14/19 1:15 AM | 1            |
|        | ABC2 | 123B    | 132456798 | 7/14/19 3:20 AM | 1            |
|        | ABC3 | 123C    | 984561325 | 7/14/19 6:09 PM | 1            |
|        | ABC4 | 123D    | 789613453 | 7/14/19 3:54 PM | 1            |
|        | ABC4 | 123D    | 789613211 | 4/19/18 4:20 AM | 1            |
|        | ABC4 | 123D    | 789611121 | 9/24/17 5:51 AM | 1            |
|        | ABC5 | 123E    | 335978456 | 7/14/19 2:10 PM | 1            |
|        | ABC5 | 123E    | 335978111 | 2/21/19 7:19 AM | 1            |
| Total  |      |         |           |                 | 8            |
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my post and I hope I'm clear when my title and what I'm needing. Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `Outage Count = COUNT(Outages[CASE_ID])`?

Comment: I need it to count Case_IDs for the past two years, but only for subitems that have been out since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is closer to this:

```
Devices w Outages 2Yr =
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[SubItem] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= TODAY() - 1
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[Case] ),
        FILTER ( Outages, Outages[SubItem] IN devices )
    )
```

This creates a list of `SubItem` values rather than the single one you get with `MAX` and that's where your `ALLSELECTED` function needs to go.

---

**Edit:** To total at the `SubItem` level try this tweak:

```
Devices w Outages 2Yr =
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[SubItem] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= TODAY() - 1,
        VALUES ( Outages[SubItem] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[Case] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[SubItem] IN devices
    )
```

The exact logic here is a bit complex for a beginner DAX user, but just keep in mind that DAX is all about filters.

For the variable `devices`, we want a list of all `SubItem` values in the current context subject to a date constraint. The `CALCULATETABLE` function allows us to modify our filter context. The `ALLSELECTED` function is a table filter removes any filter context from the visual so that all `Date` and `Case` values that aren't filtered out by slicers or page/report level filters are included. Otherwise, you'd get blanks for rows that have dates before `TODAY()-1`. The date value boolean filtering is self-explanatory, but then I add another table filter at the end, `VALUES(Outages[SubItem])`, to add back the `SubItem` context from the visual.

The `CALCULATE` piece functions similarly. We count all the `Case` values after altering the filter context to remove filter context on `Case` and `Date` and only taking `SubItem` values from the list generated in the variable.

Comment: OMG, I could kiss your right now, man (no homo) or woman. I knew I needed to create a list but I didn't know where or how, I tried to figure it out for a long time. Thank you so so so so so so so so much.

Comment: I have one more question, what is the best way to create a measure to apply total of count(case_ID) to each row.

Comment: Try `ALLSELECTED(Outages)` instead of `Outages` inside the `FILTER`.

Comment: I tried FILTER ( ALLSELECTED(Outages), Outages[SubItem] IN devices ) and just got 9 all the way down. Which equals the  total for the area.

Comment: What total are you looking for then?

Comment: Total by Sub_Item. So if you look at my second table, you would see, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 in a column.

Comment: Omg, you are a genius. Do you have any resources or recommendations for me, to understand this the way you do.

Comment: The Definitive Guide to DAX is my standard book recommendation. For websites, start here: https://www.sqlbi.com/guides/dax/

Comment: Thanks, I'll get started on that book.

Comment: If you have time, can you explain to me how this worked and your thought process.

Comment: I'm back again. How can I get the total by 'Item' not 'Sub_Item'....I'm trying to add more features to the report. Having it total by sub_item is causing me to lose data when I say I want outages greater than 5 (or whatever) by item.

Comment: I think you'll need to write a new question rather than continuing here.

Comment: Sure thing, I will do that.

Comment: *New Topic* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079017/calculate-total-by-specific-column-then-apply-column-total-to-each-row