# Calculate Total by specific column, then apply column total to each row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to apply the total count('case_id'), while grouping by the Item.

This was my previous ask [DAX Measure to calculate aggregate data, but group by Case ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044216/dax-measure-to-calculate-aggregate-data-but-group-by-case-id/57044948?noredirect=1#comment100679641_570449481123456). This gave me the total count('case_id') by sub_item.

```
Measure = 
VAR datesSelection = 
    DATE(
        YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE('Date Selection'[DateWoTime]))
        ,MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Date Selection'[DateWoTime]))
        ,DAY(SELECTEDVALUE('Date Selection'[DateWoTime]))
    )
VAR devicesTotal =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Sub_Item] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection,
        VALUES ( Outages[Sub_Item] )
    )
var counts =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED( Outages ),
        Outages[Sub_Item] IN devicesTotal
    )
return 
    counts
```

I'm getting this.

```
| Item  | Sub_Item | TYPE | Case ID    | Date             | Measure |
|-------|----------|------|------------|------------------|---------|
| 701ML | abc      | TFUS | 1312937981 | 7/16/19 7:18:00  | 1       |
| 702ML | abc      | TFUS | 1312958225 | 7/16/19 11:13:00 | 1       |
| 702ML | abc1     | TFUS | 1312957505 | 7/16/19 11:03:00 | 1       |
| 702ML | abc2     | TFUS | 1312954287 | 7/16/19 10:24:00 | 1       |
| 702ML | abc3     | TFUS | 1312938599 | 7/16/19 7:28:00  | 1       |
| 702ML | abc4     | TFUS | 1290599620 | 5/25/18 15:43:00 | 2       |
| 702ML | abc4     | TFUS | 1312950297 | 7/16/19 9:43:00  | 2       |
| 708BI | abc      | TFUS | 1312947288 | 7/16/19 9:13:00  | 1       |
| 712BI | abc      | TFUS | 1312944078 | 7/16/19 8:30:00  | 1       |
| 785DL | abc      | TFUS | 1312937536 | 7/16/19 7:12:00  | 1       |
| 786DL | abc      | TFUS | 1312992583 | 7/16/19 14:59:00 | 1       |
| 791DI | abc      | LFUS | 1289094627 | 4/28/18 20:07:00 | 2       |
| 791DI | abc      | LFUS | 1312958972 | 7/16/19 11:17:00 | 2       |
| 791DI | abc1     | LFUS | 1313005237 | 7/16/19 14:00:00 | 2       |
| 791DI | abc2     | RCLR | 1290324328 | 5/22/18 15:36:00 | 2       |
| 841JU | abc      | TFUS | 1312955016 | 7/16/19 10:32:00 | 1       |
| 841JU | abc1     | SBKR | 1288688911 | 4/15/18 10:09:56 | 2       |
| 841JU | abc1     | SBKR | 1312961007 | 7/16/19 11:46:24 | 2       |
| 871NI | abc2     | TFUS | 1304308511 | 3/24/19 19:13:00 | 2       |
| 871NI | abc      | TFUS | 1313015455 | 7/16/19 18:39:00 | 2       |
| 917CN | abc      | TFUS | 1312945831 | 7/16/19 8:58:00  | 1       |
| 918CN | abc      | LFUS | 1292611263 | 6/30/18 9:41:00  | 2       |
| 918CN | abc      | LFUS | 1313006283 | 7/16/19 17:03:00 | 2       |
| 922DU | abc      | TFUS | 1312987081 | 7/16/19 14:20:00 | 1       |
| 922DU | abc1     | TFUS | 1313005803 | 7/16/19 17:04:00 | 1       |
| 922DU | abc2     | TFUS | 1313003541 | 7/16/19 16:42:00 | 1       |
| 931LF | abc      | TFUS | 1312972165 | 7/16/19 12:46:00 | 1       |
```

When I would like to get this.

```
| Item  | Sub_Item | TYPE | Case ID    | Date            | Measure |
|-------|----------|------|------------|-----------------|---------|
| 701ML | abc      | TFUS | 1312937981 | 7/16/2019 7:18  | 1       |
| 702ML | abc      | TFUS | 1312958225 | 7/16/2019 11:13 | 6       |
| 702ML | abc1     | TFUS | 1312957505 | 7/16/2019 11:03 | 6       |
| 702ML | abc2     | TFUS | 1312954287 | 7/16/2019 10:24 | 6       |
| 702ML | abc3     | TFUS | 1312938599 | 7/16/2019 7:28  | 6       |
| 702ML | abc4     | TFUS | 1290599620 | 5/25/2018 15:43 | 6       |
| 702ML | abc4     | TFUS | 1312950297 | 7/16/2019 9:43  | 6       |
| 708BI | abc      | TFUS | 1312947288 | 7/16/2019 9:13  | 1       |
| 712BI | abc      | TFUS | 1312944078 | 7/16/2019 8:30  | 1       |
| 785DL | abc      | TFUS | 1312937536 | 7/16/2019 7:12  | 1       |
| 786DL | abc      | TFUS | 1312992583 | 7/16/2019 14:59 | 1       |
| 791DI | abc      | LFUS | 1289094627 | 4/28/2018 20:07 | 4       |
| 791DI | abc      | LFUS | 1312958972 | 7/16/2019 11:17 | 4       |
| 791DI | abc1     | LFUS | 1313005237 | 7/16/2019 14:00 | 4       |
| 791DI | abc2     | RCLR | 1290324328 | 5/22/2018 15:36 | 4       |
| 841JU | abc      | TFUS | 1312955016 | 7/16/2019 10:32 | 3       |
| 841JU | abc1     | SBKR | 1288688911 | 4/15/2018 10:09 | 3       |
| 841JU | abc1     | SBKR | 1312961007 | 7/16/2019 11:46 | 3       |
| 871NI | abc2     | TFUS | 1304308511 | 3/24/2019 19:13 | 2       |
| 871NI | abc      | TFUS | 1313015455 | 7/16/2019 18:39 | 2       |
| 917CN | abc      | TFUS | 1312945831 | 7/16/2019 8:58  | 1       |
| 918CN | abc      | LFUS | 1292611263 | 6/30/2018 9:41  | 2       |
| 918CN | abc      | LFUS | 1313006283 | 7/16/2019 17:03 | 2       |
| 922DU | abc      | TFUS | 1312987081 | 7/16/2019 14:20 | 3       |
| 922DU | abc1     | TFUS | 1313005803 | 7/16/2019 17:04 | 3       |
| 922DU | abc2     | TFUS | 1313003541 | 7/16/2019 16:42 | 3       |
| 931LF | abc      | TFUS | 1312972165 | 7/16/2019 12:46 | 1       |
```

Comment: How did you make my table look like a table last time.

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: I made some changes, feeder_device is sub_item

Comment: Thats the site I found, I will paste what was generated. I hope it comes out right.

Comment: What date do you have selected?

Comment: "07/16/2019" using a slicer, getting sub_items during that time frame. The table I have get the total case_ID 2 years back ("07/17/2017" - "07/16/2019")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what level you are aggregating at in your measure. Currently, you are aggregating at the `Sub_Item` level.

To aggregate at the `Item` level, simply replace `Sub_Item` with `Item` in your measure.

Comment: I tried that yesterday. The sub_items that should have been captured have the right data, however I then receive records for other sub_items that shouldn't have been captured.

Comment: Wait wait wait. I think I know whats going on. Give me about 10 mins. to come back to you.

Comment: OMG, I guess I was just starring at the screen for too long and couldn't make sense of what I was trying to do. I was using the measure as a check yesterday. I saw that the feeder devices that should have been selected were correct. I didn't realize that what I needed to do was remove 'measure' from my table.